# validate a user registration form

Tags: javascript, validation

I have a user registration form. I already use validation to check if all fields are filled. I need to validate email and mobile number using javascript and alert using an alertbox if its not valid. Please help

the code is

```
            var name = $("#name").val();
            var inst = $("#inst").val();
            var email = $("#email").val();
            var mobile = $("#mobile").val();
            var dataString = 'name='+ name + '&inst='+ inst + '&email='+ email +'&mobile='+ mobile;

            if(name==''|| inst=='' || email=='' || mobile=='')
            {
            alert("Please Enter all the Fields");
            }
else 
{ //rest of code comes here
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var emailRe = /^\w+([\.\-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.\-]?\w+)*\.(\w{2}|(com|net|org|edu|int|mil|gov|arpa|biz|aero|name|coop|info|pro|museum))$/;
var phoneRe = /^((\+\d{1,3}(-| )?\(?\d\)?(-| )?\d{1,5})|(\(?\d{2,6}\)?))(-| )?(\d{3,4})(-| )?(\d{4})(( x| ext)\d{1,5}){0,1}$/;
var email_address = $('#email').val();
var phone_number = $('#phone').val();

if(emailRe.test(email_address) === false){
  alert(email_address + ' is invalid');
}

if(phoneRe.test(phone_number) === false){
  alert(phone_number + ' is invalid');
}
```

Reference: [Regular Expressions Field Validation](http://javascript.about.com/library/blre.htm)